# Managing IntelliJ Tool Windows, how to

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently my `IntelliJ` shows amongst other things

[image]

How do i decide

1. What tool windows are shown
2. Where they are shown

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those things are called *Tool Windows*, and you can find them at <kbd>View > Tool Windows</kbd>.

To disable some of them, you can install the plugin [ToolWindow Manager](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=1489) and disable one by one.

You can enable/disable all tool windows in <kbd>Settings > Appearance > Show tool window bars</kbd>

You can find more information about them [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html).

Comment: Thank you for reference to ToolWindow Manager. I was struggling with this problem for quite long actually.

Comment: looks like `ToolWindow Manager` is no longer supported, can't install it

Answer (score 1):

These are called "Tool Windows".  If you right click on them it shows a menu that at the bottom has a "Hide" option.  I notice some of them can't be hidden, but you can drag them to other places that are out of your view.  For example, you can drag them from the bottom to the side.  You can also drag to answer your second question.

Comment: How would you add new? How would you know which ones (lets keep calling them plugins) are available to be added please?

Comment: I updated my question a bit after I found out what they're called.  I don't know that you can add new ones.  Maybe plugins can do it.  What are you trying to add/do?

Comment: I noticed i have `Ant` tool window which i don't use. Unfortunately it does not look like i can remove it (right click, Hide)